# Enable sprockets manifest asset paths in Rails 4 integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

In tracking down some issues which only appear in precompiled assets, I would like to write some integration tests which reference the compiled assets.  Try as I might, I have been unable to get integration tests responses which seem to reference assets that use digested paths.

I have tried adding the following to `config/environments/test.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

My layout has:

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

Before running tests I run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Now when I run the integration tests I'm expecting the responses to include links in the form of `assets/application-0f75109cfd6dc785c7bee4647913bc16.css`, but it does it's simply `assets/application.css.

How could I enable such behavior?

Comment: Have you tried RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile

Comment: @JamesKyburz great observation.  I hadn't, but unfortunately that still doesn't cause the integration tests to seem to use the digested asset paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

According to the [sprocket-rails README](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#initializer-options):

> When enabled, fingerprints will be added to asset filenames.

This works in Rails 4.2.0.rc3